# reading nested json file w/ boost

Tags: c++, json, boost

I'm trying to read a JSON formatted file which is nested with the BOOST library in C++.

I tried a couple of things, browsed through many questions in this forum, but I couldn't find anything really similar, or that would work.

the json file im looking at has the following structure

```
{
    "ABC": {
        "FF:[10.0,20.0]": {
            "GHG:[-2.5,-2.0]": {
                "value": 1.1176470518112183,
                "error": 0.013857235087295462
            },
            "GHG:[1.566,2.0]": {
                "value": 0.9958805441856384,
                "error": 0.027176504445043704
            }
        },
        "FF:[30.0,50.0]": {
            "GHG:[-2.5,-2.0]": {
                "value": 1.1176470518112183,
                "error": 0.013857235087295462
            },
            "GHG:[2.0,2.5]": {
                "value": 1.0464363098144531,
                "error": 0.061588554028766326
            }
        }        
    },
    "ZXY": {
        "FF:[10.0,20.0]": {
            "GHG:[-2.5,-2.0]": {
                "value": 1.1176470518112183,
                "error": 0.013857235087295462
            },
            "GHG:[1.566,2.0]": {
                "value": 0.9958805441856384,
                "error": 0.027176504445043704
            }
        },
        "FF:[30.0,50.0]": {
            "GHG:[-2.5,-2.0]": {
                "value": 1.1176470518112183,
                "error": 0.013857235087295462
            },
            "GHG:[2.0,2.5]": {
                "value": 1.0464363098144531,
                "error": 0.061588554028766326
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i was trying to use the BOOST_FOREACH method as is described here:
http://www.ce.unipr.it/people/medici/boost_ptree.html

```
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace pt = boost::property_tree;

pt::ptree tree;

int main() {

    pt::read_json("bla.json", tree);

    BOOST_FOREACH(  pt::ptree::value_type const&v, tree.get_child("ABC") ) {
        const std::string & key = v.first;
        const pt::ptree & subtree = v.second; 
        //const pt::ptree & subsubtree = v.second;
        std::cout << key << std::endl;
        if(subtree.empty()) {
            std::cout << "subtree empty" << std::endl;
            } else {
            std::cout << "subtree not empty" << std::endl;

            BOOST_FOREACH(  pt::ptree::value_type const&sv, subtree.get_child(key) ) {
                const std::string & subkey = sv.first; // key
                const pt::ptree & subsubtree = sv.second; // value (or a subnode)
                if(subsubtree.empty()) {
                    std::cout << "subsubtree empty" << std::endl;
                    } else {
                    std::cout << "subsubtree not empty" << std::endl;
                    std::cout << subsubtree.data() << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but i always get an error that there's no such node:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::wrapexcept<boost::property_tree::ptree_bad_path>'
  what():  No such node (FF:[10.0,20.0])
Aborted
```

i'm pretty sure this is not a hard problem, but i'm kind of a newbie with c++ and i really appreciate any help!

Comment: Once you retrieved the info from the file, there is no JSON involved anymore, so you can remove that from your question. Also, you could reduce your code to something closer to a [mcve], which would also make sure that you really know what's in the property tree.

Comment: Using BOOST_FOREACH is a really old way. C++11 provides range-based for. However, it seems that that is not the main issue.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt honestly, if i knew how to make it simpler, i would; i can start with the comments i guess?

Comment: @yumetodo my problem is that the subtree is not recognized as a node
and i don't understand why not

Comment: Well, your topic says "reading nested JSON". Did that part succeed? If yes, then there's some way to improve this question. Also, where exactly is that exception thrown? On which iteration?

Comment: reproduced: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Q79hq9lz9UUpY92N (note: rewrite with C++11 range-based for, use pt::path to avoid delimit key, use C++17 maybe_unsed attribute to disable warning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got it that your `get_child` usage is not correct! Just pass the tree to range-based for.

```cpp
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace pt = boost::property_tree;

pt::ptree tree;

int main() {

    pt::read_json("bla.json", tree);

    for(auto&& v : tree.get_child("ABC")) {
        const std::string & key = v.first; // key
        const pt::ptree & subtree = v.second; // value (or a subnode)
        //const pt::ptree & subsubtree = v.second; // value (or a subnode)
        std::cout << key << std::endl;
        if(subtree.empty()) {
            // This is a key:value
            //  use subtree.data() as string value or subtree.get_value<T>()
            std::cout << "subtree empty" << std::endl;
            } else {
            // This is a subtree
            //  use subtree as child
            std::cout << "subtree not empty" << std::endl;

            for(auto&& sv : subtree/*.get_child(pt::path(key, '\0'))*/) {
                [[maybe_unused]]const std::string & subkey = sv.first; // key
                const pt::ptree & subsubtree = sv.second; // value (or a subnode)
                std::cout << subkey << std::endl;
                if(subsubtree.empty()) {
                    std::cout << "subsubtree empty" << std::endl;
                    } else {
                    std::cout << "subsubtree not empty" << std::endl;
                    std::cout << subsubtree.data() << std::endl;
                    for(auto&& ssv: subsubtree) {
                        [[maybe_unused]]const std::string & subsubkey = ssv.first; // key
                        const pt::ptree & subsubsubtree = ssv.second; // value (or a subnode)
                        std::cout << subsubkey << std::endl;
                        if(subsubsubtree.empty()) {
                            std::cout << "subsubsubtree empty" << std::endl;
                            if (auto subsubsubtree_v = subsubsubtree.get_value_optional<double>()) {
                                std::cout << subsubsubtree_v.get() << std::endl;
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            std::cout << "subsubtree not empty" << std::endl;
                            std::cout << subsubtree.data() << std::endl;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/uRub7N5VeZ9WrDKd